# Installing OpenCV 3.0 and opencv_contrib via conda on MAC OS

Tags: python, opencv

As some features (SITF, SURF) are no longer in opencv3. Do you know what is the right procedure   to install opencv_contrib jointly with openCV via conda?
I mean something like this:

```
conda create -n opencv numpy scipy scikit-learn matplotlib python=3
source activate opencv
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

Please, see this post to see what I'm talking about:  http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to install using conda?

Comment: @jorjasso did you figure out how to install opencv3 with sift, surf etc using conda?